# Detect when the form came from light box or directly from the page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I had created a light box

```
<a href="customer.php?lightbox[width]=396&lightbox[height]=250&lightbox[modal]=true&box=1"
     class="lightbox" id="flier">Add Customer
</a>
```

I just want to find out, the form is posted from lightbox or directly through `customer.php`.

If it is from lightbox, it will reopen the lightbox until close is manually clicked.

Comment: please check of my edit is correct

Answer (score 2):

You could set a hidden form field in the form inside of the light box like this

```
<input type="hidden" name="modal" value="set" />
```

Then when the page reloads, use some PHP to see if that field is set:

```
<? if(isset($_POST['modal'])): ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#add-customer").someEventToOpenYourModal();
</script>

<? endif; ?>
```

Comment: Agreed, but it's simpler this way as I'm assuming the asker isn't too familiar with Ajax